# How to save video into database using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-3.5

I have scenario where i want to store video into database and show in grid to download from database ,i will upload video by fileupload control and it should be sql server2008  database,which is best way in c# and asp.net?

Comment: Do not store video in database. Store just its name in the table and Upload the video in folder. This i feel is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

There are many link for it. Check out this.

http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/06/21/save-and-display-youtube-video-links-on-asp-net-website.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1104451.aspx/1?How+to+retrieve+video+file+from+sql+server+database
http://www.saurabhdeveloper.com/techtips_details.php?tipsid=15
http://forums.asp.net/p/1533758/3719583.aspx
http://forums.asp.net/t/1045855.aspx/2/10
http://forums.asp.net/t/1511588.aspx/1
http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/274821-Play-video-file-asp-net-page.aspx
http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/kfra/archive/2006/10/04/50003.aspx
http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/16239-code-for-video-upload.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/88899/
http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/10-working-with-video

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/88899/

Try this code

```
 byte[] buffer;
//this is the array of bytes which will hold the data (file)

SqlConnection connection;
protected void ButtonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check the file

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile != null 
        && FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        //retrieve the HttpPostedFile object

        buffer = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        int bytesReaded = file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 
                          FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength);

        if (bytesReaded > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = 
                  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
                  "uploadConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
                ("INSERT INTO Videos (Video, Video_Name, Video_Size)" + 
                 " VALUES (@video, @videoName, @videoSize)", connection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@video", 
                    SqlDbType.VarBinary, buffer.Length).Value = buffer;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@videoName", 
                    SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FileUpload1.FileName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@videoSize", 
                    SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = file.ContentLength;
                using (connection)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Label1.Text = "uploaded, " + i.ToString() + " rows affected";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Choose a valid video file";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please extract some useful data from these links? It is quite overwhelming!

Answer (score 1):

You say it "should" be SQL Server 2008, but does it have to be?

If not, SQL Server 2012 offers [File Tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx) that are designed for storing large files in SQL Server.  It actually stores the data on the filesystem but in a way that you don't have to write any code to manage the actual file.

If it does need to be SQL Server 2008 then you have the following options:

1) [FileStream](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) using a varbinary(MAX) column type - there can be performance issues with this method. I personally would not store video in this way.

2) Put the file on the file system (on disk) and only store the filepath/filename in the DB.  You then write code to manage CRUD operations on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

It will help you... see the following link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/308552/Upload-and-Download-Files-to-SQL-Servers-in-ASP-Ne